# How can I serialize a Collection to send it using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I am trying to send a object via WCF as parameter in this method:

```
[OperationContract]
bool SendProject(Project project);
```

and I got this if i try to call it from client:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter project. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
> with data contract name 'ArrayOfDictionaryEntry:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections%27) is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
> by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.
> Please see InnerException for more details.

I search some info and I think that the error is how I serialize a class (a class from [Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)) which is inside "project" class:

```
#region ISerializable

public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    if (info == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
    }
            
    Collection<DictionaryEntry> entries = new Collection<DictionaryEntry>();
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in _keyedEntryCollection)
        entries.Add(entry);
    info.AddValue("entries", entries);
}

#endregion ISerializable
```

The problem is that I dont know where to put the tag "KnownType" or how to serialize correctly this Dictionary to send it as parameter using WCF.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that [`DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry?view=netcore-3.1) is non-generic and so WCF will not know the contracts for the keys and values.  But why are you using a non-generic dictionary from .Net 1.1?  Why not use a typed model?  WCF is designed to work with typed models.  Alternatively, if you can't use a typed model, can you share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?  At the moment you just share a code fragment that don't compile standalone.

Comment: I change the DictionaryEntry for KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> but the error just persist but this time with KeyValuePair as parameter. The Dictionary is used multiple times and it has not a type defined, it is <string, ClassA> or <string, classB>. It would be difficult send a minimal reproducible example because the code has complexity, but i think you can reproduce it dowlnoading the code from Dr.WPF link and using it in WCF in a custom class. I will try to simplify the code if this solution doesnt work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since you're just serializing a `Collection<DictionaryEntry>` (or  `Collection<KeyValuePair<string, something you haven't shown us>>`)maybe you can reproduce this with a simple `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` stored inside a root object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution, which is not so clean but is a solution.
As [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) said, updating `DictionaryEntry` to `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a recommended step, but what fixed my problem was set `[KnownType(typeof(Collection<KeyValuePair<TypeX, TypeY>>))]` in the class where the serialization is.